# Elasticsearch: get a list of indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get a list of indexes that match a certain pattern e.g

this is how to get a list of indexes:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_stats/'
```

but I couldn't find a way of filter them so that this list would only include only indexes witch match "my_index_nr_1*" where "*" would be a wild card

#### Solution

After using ES for quite a while here is what I use now, hope it will help someone else:

```
curl -XGET '/_cat/indices/my_index_nr_1*'
```

You can also add `?v` at the end which will give you headers of each column in result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a neat trick using the _aliases command that when combined with a wildcard (`my_index_nr_1*` below) will only show you matching index names and associated indexes:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index_nr_1*/_aliases?pretty'
```

The result I get is:

```
{
  "my_index_nr_1_test" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

Very helpful when you have a lot of indexes on a cluster but don't want to see all the other stats information.

Comment: I've got "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/my_index_nr_1-*/_aliases?pretty] and method [GET], allowed: [PUT]"

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work anymore since ES6. Getting the same error as heroin.

Comment: Just found out this works for all versions: `/my_index_nr_1*/_alias` instead of `/my_index_nr_1*/_aliases`

Answer (score 15):

For humans, the best answer is the modified summary:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices/my_index_nr_1*?v
```

For machines, the best answer is likely a variation of (`?pretty` is there for you to see its output):

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index_nr_1*/_settings?pretty
```

This will get the list of all indices that match, with their settings. The `_aliases` answer above is just a variation of this request. You can even trim the request down to:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index_nr_1*?pretty
```

However, this will respond with both the settings, aliases, and mappings of each index.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index_nr_1*/_stats'
```

Comment: this doesn't really do the job, because if my_index_nr_1* doesn't match anything it gives me back all indexes instead of none.