# Elasticsearch cat indices in JSON format

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 1.7, I want to see the results of `_cat/indices` in  JSON format.  I understand [the results are meant to be aligned/pretty/readable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/cat.html), but is there a way to convert it to JSON using Elasticsearch API?

Comment: Why not use the regular api then?

Comment: @FrederickCheung - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you suggesting I just deal with the non-JSON format and convert it myself?  I may have to do that, but just thought if it was available to do something like ```_cat/indices?json=true``` that would be easier.  It's really a yes/no question I suppose.

Comment: I mean the _cat api presents a text version of the json apis, e.g.  /_stats, so if you want json, why not use /_stats (or whatever the right api is for your use) directly

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Thank you, that got me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### Append `format` param, eg: `_cat/indices?format=json`

You can also make it pretty-formatted with: `_cat/indices?format=json&pretty=true`

Comment: I haven't tested this on Elasticsearch 1.7, but it works great on v2.2.4.  Thumbs up!

Answer (score 8):

Per [the documentation of cat APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/cat.html):

> JSON is great… for computers. Even if it’s pretty-printed, trying to find relationships in the data is tedious. Human eyes, especially when looking at an ssh terminal, need compact and aligned text. The cat API aims to meet this need.

In other words, the cat API is designed to give data in this format. So you will want to use a different form of the API. The problem is (at least this was my problem) that googling "elasticsearch list indices" brings up the cat API as the first result, so this question is pretty reasonable.

To get all of the indices in JSON form, it's as easy as running this:

```
GET /*/_stats
```

That's a lot of data though. You likely want JSON because you want to do some sort of processing on it. Going back to how I found this question, I actually wanted to get a list of indices sorted by the store size and I didn't want to have to use `curl` and `sort` unix commands to do so. That command looks like this:

```
GET /*/_stats/store
```

Unfortunately, the sort in the search body won't work for the `_stats` command (at least, I haven't been able to make it work). But adding the `store` attribute will make it so you only get back the information about the data stores for each index.

More information about the metrics attributes can be found in [the _stats documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-stats.html).

Comment: For my case I only need the index names, so I prefer ```/*/_aliases``` over ```/*/_stats``` because it has less data and gets results faster, but this is good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: @chevin99 yeah, every use case is different, just wanted to share mine. I happened to be looking for the same thing just hours after you posted your question so I thought I'd drop an answer

Answer (score 4):

In general with this and other REST apis, set the "Accept" header to the content type you need. For example, with elasticsearch 5.1.1 you need to specify "application/json" as the accepted content type and elasticsearch will honor that.

Comment: Not sure why this answer isn't much more popular, tbh.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell maybe it is because headers are harder to set than url parameters? For example I do not know how to set them in the Kibana Dev Tools. This might make headers less usable to most users.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done by adding format=json at the end.

```
localhost:9200/_cat/indices?format=json
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I can get what I need using `/*/_aliases` and use all the keys of the response, [similar to what is suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371439/elasticsearch-get-a-list-of-indexes).