# elasticsearch cat indices nodejs API json output

Tags: elasticsearch

Using [elasticsearch JS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html) client,if I want to get all the indices, it provides an API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-cat-indices

However, the output format is string.
If I want to find the latest index, I need to manipulate the string such as split by space, iterate thru the array and filter the content by some criteria etc..

Instead, Is it possible to get json output from the API?

PS: I did notice this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994868/elasticsearch-cat-indices-in-json-format) which is suggesting to use `/*/_aliases` and that works well but I was wondering how to leverage elasticsearch js client APIs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cat APIs are meant to be consumed by humans (hence not JSON).

If you want to get JSON data, you can use the [`indices.stats`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-stats) call (which hits the [`/_stats`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-stats.html) API endpoint).

```
client.indices.stats({
   index: "_all",
   level: "indices"
}, function(err, res) {
   // res contains JSON data about indices stats
});
```

**UPDATE**:

Actually, the cat APIs also return JSON data, if you specify the parameter `format: json` in the request:

```
client.cat.indices({"format": "json"}, function(err, res) {
    ...
});
```